# Square area equal to difference between the circumscribed circle and the inscribed circle

Tags: proof-verification

There is no such square whose area is equal to the difference between the areas of its circumscribed and inscribed circles. Am I right?

Imagine a square with length $L$.
This square has an area of $L^2$.
Its inscribed circle has radius $\frac{L}{2}$.
Hence, it has an area of $π \frac{L^2}{4}$.
By Pythagoras' theorem, the circumscribed circle has a radius of $\sqrt 2L$.
So it has an area of $2πL^2$.

A.T.Q.  :
\begin{align}
\text{Area of circumscribed circle - Area of inscribed circle} &= \text{Area of a square} \\
2πL^2 - π\frac{L^2}{4} & \neq L^2
\end{align}

Does this complete my proof?

Comment: Circumscribed and inscribed circles of what, exactly? Any convex polygon?

Comment: "If any one wants to know my proof just request it." - That's not how [tag:proof-verification] works.

Comment: Also, probably you meant "constructible in finitely many steps with straightedge and compass".

Comment: Typically, posts tagged "proof-verification" include a proof, with the question, "Is my proof correct?"  Since I don't see your proof, I'm not sure what it is that you want us to do...

Comment: The polygon I mean is the square. And I am quite unsure whether my profile is right. Anyway I am adding my proof.

Comment: @user202729 This isn't about constructability, but the area of the annulus given by the circumscribed and inscribed circles of a square, compared to the area of the square itself.

Comment: I request you for that proof 

Comment: So is my proof accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right, I suppose? π is not equal to 4.

Comment: See your revised post. In it you provided a counter-example, which, indeed, proves your assertion. For rigorousness, you may want to remark that every square is completely defined by the length of its sides.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: In fact I expanded on this idea: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579805/no-polygon-has-the-same-area-as-the-difference-between-its-inscribed-and-circums/2580922#2580922